# int_fast32_t and int_fast16_t are typedefs of int. How is it supposed to be used?

Tags: c++, c

*stdint.h* defines:

int32_t, *int_least32_t*, *int_fast16_t* and *int_fast32_t* as just **int** data type

How exactly they are different and how is it useful?
I'm ecpecially confused with the part of "*int_fast16_t* and *int_fast32_t*".
16 and 32 bits are implemented under the default int. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Have you read the specifications for these types? The actual type that these are synonyms for will vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: It turns out that on *your* computer the fastest way to handle 16 bits might be to put them in an `int`. If the answer had *always* been "use a `short`", we wouldn't have needed these typedefs.

Comment: @BoPersson can you breifly explain different systems? I was taught that a compiler simple translates src to asm of a target platform. the ISA defines what data types we have, doesn't it? I can see on my windows 10 x64, using msvs compiler that those types i mentioned in the actual question are defined under int data type. So when i compile any program, it doesn't really matter which one of those i want to use, it will use 32bit int even though i might want a 16 bit version for a proper data alignment as an example. What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: If you want exactly 16 bits, you should use `int16_t`. However, on a 32 or 64 bit version of the x86, the 16-bit instructions are larger than the "native" size instructions and therefore take slightly more time. On most systems `int` is selected as the fastest type available, so a good choice for the "fastXX" versions.

Comment: @BoPersson.: Also if someone chooses `int_least16_t` compiler will assume that if provided with 32 bit the OP won't complain. The type that meets the need with atleast 16 bits will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well the header [implementation](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdint_8h_source.html) mentions the reasons clearly

> To accommodate targets that are missing types that are exactly `8`, `16`,
>   `32`, or    `64` bits wide, this implementation takes an approach of
>   cascading
>       redefintions, redefining `__int_leastN_t` to successively smaller exact-width
>       types.

Further more checking the section of this [description](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdint.h) (Minimum-width integer types) is helpful:-

> The standard mandates that these have widths greater than or equal to
>   `N`, and that no smaller type with the same signedness has `N` or more
>   bits. For example, if a system provided only a `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`,
>   `uint_least16_t` must be equivalent to `uint32_t`.

Comment: ermm. Imagine x86 ISA is missing 16 bit int. In C spec, i have int that is 32 bits wide by default. After compilation, i will have x86 assembly of that default int because each one of those 4 typedefs are eventually come down to that default 32 int. How typedefs can affect the type feature of a language?

Comment: @Richard.: The standard doesn't say anything on this other than the relative sizes of the types. Now the implementation of compilers does use these kind of things to provide end user with the suitable types. That's why this segregation is needed as the end user may belong to different systems having different architectures etc etc. *The language doesn't - the implementation does.*

Answer (score 0):

**int16_t** is an integer which takes exactly 16 bits.

**intfast16_t** is a platform dependent implementation. On a 32 bit architecture, int16_t is misaligned and inefficient, as it has to first realigned in 32bit registers during load. intfast16_t is 32 bit memory aligned and takes more memory, but more efficient.

**intleast16_t** is also a platform dependent implementation. It is a packed implementation which is memory efficient, but inefficient when considering performance.

Similar is the case of **int32_t**, **intfast32_t** and **intleast32_t**.

Your's may be a 32bit architecture. That is why intfast16_t, int32_t, intfast32_t and intleast32_t are all defined as int, all are 32bit aligned. intfast16_t takes 32 bit, that is it.